# Ubuntu 16.04 VIM without python support!

Tags: apt, python, 16.04, vim, python3

Although Ubuntu 16.04 release notes mention that:

**The default VIM package has been built against python3 instead of python2.**

Yet after I installed vim with the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install vim
```

And checked:

```
vim --version
```

It showed:

```
-python
-python3
```

Is it a bug? How do I get vim with Python support?

Answer (score 27):

If you want Python 3 support in vim, <strike>install the `vim-nox` package (`sudo apt install vim-nox`)</strike> *see edit below*.

However, if you still need Python 2 support, install the `vim-nox-py2` package (`sudo apt install vim-nox-py2`).

**Edit**: `vim` was recently updated to fix this issue, and you should not need to install the `vim-nox` package anymore to get Python 3 support.

Comment: yeah i did that..but why is the vim package not supporting python?

Comment: Ubuntu split the Python support from the main package into two other packages: one that supports Python 2 and one that supports Python 3. After you install one of the above packages, you should be able to use vim with Python 2/3 support.

Comment: isn't it surprising that the vim package itself doesn't support any of the pythons? the release notes mention otherwise.
https://wiki.ubuntu.com/XenialXerus/ReleaseNotes

Comment: @saiarcot895 This apparently works for me. But where did you dig this info up? Is there a Ubuntu wiki documenting  how they distribute stuff?

Comment: @qweruiop In this case, I looked at what packages were being made from the `vim` source package (open up the Xenial section [here](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/vim)), and checked what dependencies some of the binary packages had.

Comment: Just wanted to add that after installing `vim-nox-py2` I needed to run `sudo update-alternatives --set vim /usr/bin/vim.nox-py2`.  I believe, please correct me otherwise,  without this `vim` points to `vim.tiny` or some such package which doesn't have python support.

Answer (score 3):

In 17.10-18.10 it is difficult to get a copy of vim with both python2 and python3 support.  The PPA setup by [pi-rho](https://launchpad.net/~pi-rho/+archive/ubuntu/dev) has such packages for previous releases, but nothing yet for 17.10 and later.

This is what I did to get pi-rho packages running:

1. uninstall all vim packages (this will force you to uninstall "ubuntu-minimal")
2. download the vim packages from [here](http://ppa.launchpad.net/pi-rho/dev/ubuntu/pool/main/v/vim/) that end in a "~z"
3. download the packages [perl-modules-5.24](http://launchpadlibrarian.net/345240152/perl-modules-5.24_5.24.1-2ubuntu1.1_all.deb),[libgdbm3](http://launchpadlibrarian.net/264797245/libgdbm3_1.8.3-14_amd64.deb), and [libperl5.24](http://launchpadlibrarian.net/345240148/libperl5.24_5.24.1-2ubuntu1.1_amd64.deb)
4. install them using dpkg: go to the download directory and do `sudo dpkg -i libgdbm3_1.8.3-14_amd64.deb libperl5.24_5.24.1-2ubuntu1.1_amd64.deb perl-modules-5.24_5.24.1-2ubuntu1.1_all.deb vim*.deb`
5. reinstall "ubuntu-minimal": `sudo apt install ubuntu-minimal`
6. lock the vim version

   - open synaptic package manager and highlight the vim packages you just installed.  Go to Package->"Lock Version"
   - you may also need to "hold" the packages with `sudo apt-mark hold` for each of those packages (e.g. `sudo apt-mark hold vim-common vim-gnome`)

Answer (score 2):

Try installing vim-gnome instead of vim.

```
sudo apt-get install vim-gnome
```

If that can help, you can install the package python-support by downloading the latest version of python-support_X.X.X_all.deb there : https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/python-support
Open a terminal in same folder and install with:

```
dpkg -i python-support_X.X.X_all.deb
```

See if it helps

Comment: is that a gui version?

Answer (score 1):

On **Ubuntu 17.10**, compiling is the solution that worked for me:

Directly inspired by [this gist](https://gist.github.com/odiumediae/3b22d09b62e9acb7788baf6fdbb77cf8), I did the following:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge vim vim-runtime vim-gnome vim-tiny vim-gui-common
sudo apt-get install checkinstall
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/share/vim /usr/bin/vim
cd /tmp && git clone https://github.com/vim/vim
cd vim/src
make distclean
cd ..
./configure --enable-multibyte --enable-perlinterp=dynamic --enable-pythoninterp=dynamic --with-python-config-dir=/usr/lib/python2.7/config-x86_64-linux-gnu --enable-cscope --enable-gui=auto --with-features=huge --with-x --enable-fontset --enable-largefile --disable-netbeans --with-compiledby="put your name here" --enable-fail-if-missing
make
sudo make install
sudo ln -s /usr/local/bin/vim /usr/bin/vim
```

Don't forget to adapt the `./configure` parameters so you have all the other features you need.

Now you can open vim and run the command `:echo has('python')` to confirm you have python 2 enabled.

Answer (score 1):

Installing `vim-nox-py2` and then running

```
sudo update-alternatives --config vim
```

worked for me.