# `Error: Required vim compiled with +python` with VIM on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, python, vim

on my newly installed Ubuntu 18.04, I used `sudo apt install vim` to install vim. However, everytime when I type `vim` in the terminal, the error `Error: Required vim compiled with +python` just appears.

I have tried to find the solutions, but unfortunately none of them works for me. It seems [one of the proposed method](https://askubuntu.com/questions/764882/ubuntu-16-04-vim-without-python-support) on Ubuntu 16.04 is to install packages like `vim-*-py2`, but I do not find such packages on the repository of Ubuntu 18.04. And another proposed method seems to be compiling vim from the source instead of installing it with `apt install`, however, I found it is too comolicated for me to try.

I have faced this problems on two seperate PCs of mine with newly installed Ubuntu 18.04. Is this a common issue on Ubuntu 18.04 with vim installed with apt? Do you know how to fix that annoying error message?

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Have you seen this [article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30617683/required-vim-compiled-with-python) ?

Comment: Did you have a pre-existing `~/.vimrc` file that might be trying to load a plugin that depends on python2 rather than python3?

Comment: Yes, I keep my `home` directory unchanged from previous installed Ubuntu 14.04 or 16.04. So I need to remove the config file `~/.vimrc` and reinstall vim?

Comment: Reinstalling vim should not be necessary - just move or rename your `~/.vimrc` file (or identify which old plugin is causing the error and edit/comment it out)

Comment: Thanks for your instruction! I found that the `md_instant` plugin which locates in the `~/.vim` directory caused the error message. After delete the related one file and one folder, the problem has been fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Try running the following commands in a shell:

```
sudo apt-get purge vim && sudo apt-get install vim
```

This completely removes vim, including all configuration files, and installs it again.

Comment: Hi, thanks! Could you please explain more about the reason which causes the problem? I want to keep the configurations of mine if it is possible.

Comment: Generally because of broken installs but then again answering without taking a look at your installation would rather prove wrong.

And you could refer the following article for installation https://medium.com/@silviachen_76118/setup-vim-with-python-in-ubuntu-18-04-4d85cc07d679